# Does android grant permission fellow app install order?

Tags: android, permissions

AppA define permissionA in manifest like

```
package="com.example.definepermission"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >    
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <permission 
     android:name="com.example.permission.test.permissionA"
     android:protectionLevel="normal"
     >         
 </permission>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:permission="com.example.permission.test.permissionA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And AppB request AppA activity like

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.test.permissionA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

private void startNewActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.example.definepermission", "com.example.definepermission.MainActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

from pkms dump

```
$ dumpp com.example.redfinepermission
Activity Resolver Table:
  Non-Data Actions:
      android.intent.action.MAIN:
        701f87f com.example.redfinepermission/.MainActivity

Key Set Manager:
  [com.example.redfinepermission]
      Signing KeySets: 37

Packages:
  Package [com.example.redfinepermission] (6c7b04c):
    userId=10089
    pkg=Package{1856895 com.example.redfinepermission}
    codePath=/data/app/com.example.redfinepermission-1
    resourcePath=/data/app/com.example.redfinepermission-1
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/data/app/com.example.redfinepermission-1/lib
    primaryCpuAbi=null
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    versionCode=1 targetSdk=21
    versionName=1.0
    splits=[base]
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{3e91daa com.example.redfinepermission}
    flags=[ HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    dataDir=/data/user/0/com.example.redfinepermission
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    timeStamp=2016-12-13 20:57:27
    firstInstallTime=2016-12-13 20:57:27
    lastUpdateTime=2016-12-13 20:57:27
    signatures=PackageSignatures{cc79d9b [3e58538]}
    installPermissionsFixed=true installStatus=1
    pkgFlags=[ HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    requested permissions:
      com.example.permission.test.permissionA
    User 0:  installed=true hidden=false stopped=true notLaunched=true enabled=0
      runtime permissions:
    User 10:  installed=true hidden=false stopped=true notLaunched=true enabled=0
      runtime permissions:
```

$ dumpp com.example.definepermission

```
Activity Resolver Table:
  Non-Data Actions:
      android.intent.action.MAIN:
        6e05ed9 com.example.definepermission/.MainActivity

Permissions:
  Permission [com.example.permission.test.permissionA] (f44b09e):
    sourcePackage=com.example.definepermission
    uid=10090 gids=null type=0 prot=normal
    perm=Permission{643877f com.example.permission.test.permissionA}
    packageSetting=PackageSetting{943934c com.example.definepermission/10090}

Key Set Manager:
  [com.example.definepermission]
      Signing KeySets: 24

Packages:
  Package [com.example.definepermission] (943934c):
    userId=10090
    pkg=Package{16f0f95 com.example.definepermission}
    codePath=/data/app/com.example.definepermission-1
    resourcePath=/data/app/com.example.definepermission-1
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/data/app/com.example.definepermission-1/lib
    primaryCpuAbi=null
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    versionCode=1 targetSdk=21
    versionName=1.0
    splits=[base]
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{54738aa com.example.definepermission}
    flags=[ DEBUGGABLE HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    dataDir=/data/user/0/com.example.definepermission
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    timeStamp=2016-12-13 20:57:46
    firstInstallTime=2016-12-13 20:57:46
    lastUpdateTime=2016-12-13 20:57:46
    signatures=PackageSignatures{131c9b [5bc9838]}
    installPermissionsFixed=true installStatus=1
    pkgFlags=[ DEBUGGABLE HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    declared permissions:
      com.example.permission.test.permissionA: prot=normal, INSTALLED
    User 0:  installed=true hidden=false stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0
      runtime permissions:
    User 10:  installed=true hidden=false stopped=true notLaunched=true enabled=0
      runtime permissions:
```

and run AppB will catch exception

```
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.redfinepermission, PID: 4109

    12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.example.definepermission/.MainActivity } from ProcessRecord{ad97706 4109:com.example.redfinepermission/u0a89} (pid=4109, uid=10089) requires com.example.permission.test.permissionA

12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2658)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.example.redfinepermission.MainActivity.startNewActivity(MainActivity.java:31)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.example.redfinepermission.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-13 20:59:01.323  4109  4109 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
```

If first install AppA, android setting.mPermission will contain  com.example.permission.test.permissionA, and install AppB, android will grant this normal permission to AppB .

This case can reproduce in google nexus, HW mate8, vivo.
And google map new version first install on china's andorid phone(only seal in china), and intall google gms (google play service) leat, this will reproduce this case too.

log:

Line 36607: 12-13 12:23:26.937  2032  3210 D PackageManager: com.google.android.apps.maps perm com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION grant:1
Line 36609: 12-13 12:23:26.937  2032  3210 W PackageManager: Not granting permission com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION to package com.google.android.apps.maps because it was previously installed without

Answer (score 2):

> Does android grant permission fellow app install order?

Yes. Quoting [myself](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/#usage-checkcustompermissions) from a few years ago:

> Custom permissions in Android are "first one in wins". In other words, whatever app first has a `<permission>` element for a given `android:name` gets to define, for all subsequent apps, what the details are for that permission.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void grantPermissionsLPw(PackageParser.Package pkg, boolean replace,
        String packageOfInterest) {

    ...

   if (grant != GRANT_DENIED) {
                if(DEBUG_PERMISSION){
                    Slog.d(TAG,"\tps:"+ps+" permissionFix:"+ps.installPermissionsFixed+" origPermissions:"+origPermissions);
                }
                if (!isSystemApp(ps) && ps.installPermissionsFixed) {
                    **// If this is an existing, non-system package, then
                    // we can't add any new permissions to it.** // why ??
                    if (!allowedSig && !origPermissions.hasInstallPermission(perm)) {

                        if(DEBUG_PERMISSION){
                            Slog.d(TAG,"\tpkg:"+pkg+" perm:"+perm);
                        }

                        // Except...  if this is a permission that was added
                        // to the platform (note: need to only do this when
                        // updating the platform).
                        if (!isNewPlatformPermissionForPackage(perm, pkg)) {
                            grant = GRANT_DENIED;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //add for app lose permission begin
                if(grant == GRANT_DENIED){
                    if(level == PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_NORMAL){
                            grant = GRANT_INSTALL;
                           //for normal, just grant.
                        }else {
                            allowedSig = grantSignaturePermission(perm, pkg, bp, origPermissions);
                            if(allowedSig){
                                 //and if signature equal or system app, let get it.
                                 grant = GRANT_INSTALL;
                            }
                        }
                        Slog.i(TAG,"*check signature*  level:"+level+" "+pkg.packageName+" perm:"+perm+" grant:"+grant+" allowedSig:"+allowedSig +" bp:"+bp);
                }
                //add for app lose permission begin


                switch (grant) {
                    case GRANT_INSTALL: {
                        // Revoke this as runtime permission to handle the case of
                        // a runtime permission being downgraded to an install one.
                        for (int userId : UserManagerService.getInstance().getUserIds()) {
                            if (origPermissions.getRuntimePermissionState(
                                    bp.name, userId) != null) {
                                // Revoke the runtime permission and clear the flags.
                                origPermissions.revokeRuntimePermission(bp, userId);
                                origPermissions.updatePermissionFlags(bp, userId,
                                      PackageManager.MASK_PERMISSION_FLAGS, 0);
                                // If we revoked a permission permission, we have to write.
                                changedRuntimePermissionUserIds = ArrayUtils.appendInt(
                                        changedRuntimePermissionUserIds, userId);
                            }
                        }
```

this can solve this issus, but  i want to know why ?

**// If this is an existing, non-system package, then
                        // we can't add any new permissions to it.